# creating cv folds from a dataset that has to be grouped on two featues and also time series data

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

Edit Dec 3 2020: updated the code
Edit: Following are the two changes
0a. uses sets to check there are duplicate random numbers generated
0b. We are now going from minority class to majority class to maintain class ditribution
I am working on the Kaggle home credit dataset. I am trying to work with installment_payment.csv. I joined this with application_train.csv to get the TARGET variable into installment_payment.csv. Now, my data looks like this

SK_ID_CURR SK_ID_PREV DAYS_INSTALMENT DAYS_ENTRY_PAYMENT TARGET AMT_ANNUITY DAYS_DECISION ...

1 1 .... .... 0 0.1

1 2 .... .... 0 0.2

1 3 .... .... 0 0.1

2 4 .... .... 1 0.3

2 5 .... .... 1 0.4

3 6 .... .... 0 0.2

4 7 .... .... 1 0.1

4 8 .... .... 1 0.3

4 9 .... .... 1 0.5

To create a cross validation dataset that has not any data leak I need to create a dataset that does the following

1. Combination of SK_ID_CURR and SK_ID_PREV  should exist only in one of the train folds and certainly not exist in both train and test folds.
2. Distribution of class labels should be in the same in all the folds
3. DAYS_INSTALLMENT and DAYS_ENTRY_PAYMENT are to be used as time series markers

```
    def strtfied_grp_kfld(self,fnme,nfolds):
        """
            sklearn does not have GroupkFoldStratified
            refer github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13621
            Even in that the groups cannot be of multiple levels
            But in this case study I needed grouping on two columns hence the birth of this function
            1. I have tried to ensure that the a group occurs only in one of the folds either train\test
            2. Due to class imbalance and to keep the same distribution of minor/major classes. I compute
               class weights of major and minor classes. For every majority class I create the corresponding 
               number of minority samples. I hope this will maintain the same distribution of major and minor classses across the folds.
            3. the main disadvantage is the total numner of rows will be less than x_train.shape[0] / number of folds
        """
        #total number of rows in the dataset
        nrows = self.X_train.shape[0]   
        print('no of rows',nrows)
        #number of rows in each fold
        nrowsfld = int(nrows/nfolds)
        #lst_cols = ['SK_ID_CURR','TARGET']
        #attach TARGET to taining data
        #self.X_train['TARGET'] = self.y_train
        pmyname_cv = fnme[:-16]         
        
        #print(df_tgt_1)
        #compute the class weights since this is an im balanced dataset
        print('Computing Class weights...')
        clas_wts_arr = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(self.y_train),self.y_train)   
        wt_clas_maj = clas_wts_arr[0]
        wt_clas_min = int(clas_wts_arr[1])
        print('wt clas maj',wt_clas_maj,wt_clas_min)
        #set upper bound for random number generation 
        rndm_endrange_tgt0 = self.df_tgt_0.shape[0]-1
        rndm_endrange_tgt1 = self.df_tgt_1.shape[0]-1
        no_rndm_gen_tgt1 = int(rndm_endrange_tgt1/ nfolds)
        
        print('tgt0 tgt1',rndm_endrange_tgt0,rndm_endrange_tgt1)
        #housekeeping initializations
        fld = 0
        itr_cntot_trn = 0
        itr_rndm_nos_trn = None
        tot_row_cnt = 0
        lst_trn_idx_0 = []
        lst_trn_idx_1 = []
        all_trn_idx = []
        trn_idx = []
        tst_idx = []
        set_trn_idx_0 = set()
        set_trn_idx_1 = set()  
            
        #set seed for the random number generation
        np.random.seed(84)
        print('n rows per fold',nrowsfld )
        #main loop to control number of folds
        while (fld < nfolds):
            #vairbales that need to be intialized for every fold
            itr_cntot_trn = 0
            lst_trn_idx = []      
            lst_trn_idx_0 = []
            lst_trn_idx_1 = []

            
            min_tgt_1_sum = 0
            

            #for rndm_tgt1 in rndm_no_tgt_1:            
            for i in range(no_rndm_gen_tgt1):
                #multiple random number depends on the minority class weight
                rndm_no_tgt_1 = np.random.choice(range(rndm_endrange_tgt1),replace=False)
                if fld == 0:
                    set_trn_idx_1.add(rndm_no_tgt_1)  
                    lst_trn_idx_1.append(rndm_no_tgt_1)
                else:
                    if rndm_no_tgt_1 in set_trn_idx_1:
                        continue
                    else:
                        set_trn_idx_1.add(rndm_no_tgt_1)
                        lst_trn_idx_1.append(rndm_no_tgt_1)
                #get multiple rows for minority class
                df_min_tgt_1 = self.df_tgt_1.iloc[rndm_no_tgt_1]                
                min_tgt_1_sum += df_min_tgt_1['TARGET'].sum()

            #print('num min clas to retrieve set',no_rndm_gen_tgt1,set_trn_idx_1)
            maj_num_tgt0 =min_tgt_1_sum * wt_clas_min
            maj_tgt_0_bal = 0
            while(maj_tgt_0_bal <= maj_num_tgt0):
                #generate one random number for majority class
                rndm_no_tgt_0 = np.random.choice(range(rndm_endrange_tgt0),replace=False)
                
                #get one row from majority class using generated random number
                df_maj_tgt_0 = self.df_tgt_0.iloc[[rndm_no_tgt_0]]
                
                maj_tgt_0_bal +=   df_maj_tgt_0['TARGET'].sum()
                if fld == 0:
                    set_trn_idx_0.add(rndm_no_tgt_0)
                    lst_trn_idx_0.append(rndm_no_tgt_0)
                else:
                    if rndm_no_tgt_0 in set_trn_idx_0:
                        continue
                    else:
                        set_trn_idx_0.add(rndm_no_tgt_0)
                        lst_trn_idx_0.append(rndm_no_tgt_0)                    
            #print('set majority  clas', set_trn_idx_0)
            #use ids to get actual idx's from X_train and append to list train index
            print('Generating actual indices for target 0...')
            for groupidx_0 in lst_trn_idx_0:
                #print('while loog tgt_o shape',groupidx)
                df_grp_0 = self.df_tgt_0.iloc[groupidx_0]
                #print(df_grp)
                df_act_grp_0 = self.X_train[(self.X_train['SK_ID_CURR'] == df_grp_0['SK_ID_CURR']) & (self.X_train['SK_ID_PREV'] == df_grp_0['SK_ID_PREV'])]
                #print(df_act_grp)
                for i in range(len(df_act_grp_0)) :             
                    idx_0 = self.X_train[(self.X_train['SK_ID_CURR'] == df_grp_0['SK_ID_CURR']) & (self.X_train['SK_ID_PREV'] == df_grp_0['SK_ID_PREV'])].index.values.astype(int)[i] #df_act_grp.index[i]                    
                    #print(self.X_train.iloc[[idx]])
                    lst_trn_idx.append(idx_0)
            print('Finished Generating actual indices for target 0...')
            print('Generating actual indices for target 1...')
            #use ids to get actual idx's from X_train and append to list train index
            for groupidx_1 in lst_trn_idx_1:            
                df_grp_1 = self.df_tgt_1.iloc[groupidx_1]
                #print(df_grp)
                df_act_grp_1 = self.X_train[(self.X_train['SK_ID_CURR'] == df_grp_1['SK_ID_CURR']) & (self.X_train['SK_ID_PREV'] == df_grp_1['SK_ID_PREV'])]
                #print(df_act_grp)
                for i in range(len(df_act_grp_1)) :             
                    idx_1 = self.X_train[(self.X_train['SK_ID_CURR'] == df_grp_1['SK_ID_CURR']) & (self.X_train['SK_ID_PREV'] == df_grp_1['SK_ID_PREV'])].index.values.astype(int)[i] #df_act_grp.index[i]                    
                    #print(self.X_train.iloc[[idx]])
                    lst_trn_idx.append(idx_1)
            print('Finished Generating actual indices for target 1...')
            print('total rows generated',len(lst_trn_idx))
            #we are writing to a file for debug purpose will be removed in the final version or
            #a debug flag can be used
            """
            print('writing list to file...')             
            fname = './output/'+pmyname_cv+'fold_idx_'+str(fld)+'.csv'
            print(fname)
            with open(fname,'w')  as fp:
                for item in lst_trn_idx:
                    fp.write(str(item)+',')
                    fp.write('\n')   
            print('writing list to file over.')        
            """
            all_trn_idx.append(lst_trn_idx)
            print('***len of trn idx***', len(all_trn_idx))
            #fold counter to repeat the above process for the required number of folds            
            fld += 1
        print('Generation of indices for all folds over...')

        print('Re shaping the index array for CV compatibility...')
        for i in np.arange(5):
            trn_idx = () #list not hashable []
            tst_idx = () #list not hashable[]

            fname = './output/'+pmyname_cv+'trn_idx_'+str(i)+'.csv'
            print(fname)
            fname1='./output/'+pmyname_cv+'tst_idx_'+str(i)+'.csv'
            print(fname)            
            for j in np.arange(5):
                if  i ==j:
                    #store the test set
                    idx = all_trn_idx[i]
                    #print(idx)
                    #tst_idx.append(idx)
                    for indx in idx:
                        tst_idx += (indx,)
                  
                else:
                    #store train set
                    idx =  all_trn_idx[j]
                    #trn_idx.append(idx)
                    for indx in idx:
                        trn_idx +=(indx,)                 
            
            tmp_tpl = [list(trn_idx),list(tst_idx)]
            
            print(i,j, nfolds,type(trn_idx),type(tst_idx))
            """
            with open(fname,'w')  as fp:
                for item in trn_idx:
                    fp.write(str(item)+',')
                    fp.write('\n')    
                    
            with open(fname1,'w')  as fp:
                for item in tst_idx:
                    fp.write(str(item)+',')
                    fp.write('\n')   
            """        
            #when all the folds are over return a tuple containind list of train and test indices    
            self.cv_lst_tpl.append(tmp_tpl)  #outer container cannot be list .append(tmp_tpl)
        #print(self.cv_lst_tpl[0])
        print('Generation of CV indices over.')
```

The problem I am facing is that I am getting an ROC_AUC_SCORE of 1 for my test dataset.
I think this is because the time related rows are mixed between the folds.

**My question**

1. How should I include the time related features into the above code so that future  rows are not
   present in the test dataset
2. Should the same criteria be followed for rows between the folds
3. Can logistic regression be used as a machine learning model for this type of data

thanks for your replies

Comment: For Question 1,I have taken all rows earlier than 3 years as my training set and all rows less than 3 years as my test set

Comment: split0_test_score 0.507268 split 1.0.515553 split2.0.502801 split3.0.540004
split4. 0.519538
roc auc score preview 1.0 the cv soores on the different folds are different by the roc_auc_score for test set is 1 Any ideas on how to getrid of this kind of data leakage